# QT QWebEngineView with printJS

Tags: c++, qt, printjs

I am trying to somehow enable printing through printJS library with QWebEngineView. Everything is working perfectly when opening it through the web browser, and I can't make it work with QWebEngineView.

I have tried catching a signal QWebEnginePage::printRequested and it works only with a simple window.print() JS call. I have also already tried setting all the flags to true on the QWebEngineSettings without success. My code (mostly from tutorial as I was trying to make it as simple as possible) is:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebEngineView view;
    view.setUrl(QUrl("http://localhost:8080/"));
    view.resize(1024, 750);
    view.show();

    //PrintHandler handler;
    //handler.setPage(view.page());

    return a.exec();
}
```

PrintHandler is taken from Qt5 tutorial 'PrintMe example' (it also didn't work to catch printJS signal, therefore I left it commented)

My HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>PrintMe</title>
      <script src="print.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.min.css">
      <script>
      function printNow() {
         printJS('http://localhost:8080/dummy.pdf');
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form class="form">
         <div class="header">
            <h2>Click the button to print</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="printNow()">Print Now</button>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

And printJS library is downloaded from official source.

Is there a way for QWebEngineView to react on printJS call?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround.

To have a signal in QT from printJS call it is enough to connect signal from `QWebEngineProfile::downloadRequested`. QWebEngineProfile can be got from `(QWebEngineProfile::page())::profile()`, I am doing it like this:

```
connect(view.page()->profile(), &QWebEngineProfile::downloadRequested, &view, [&](QWebEngineDownloadItem* it){
        it->setDownloadFileName("file.pdf");
        it->accept(); });
```

The file is downloaded in downloads/file.pdf (default) - of course, have to wait for `QWebEngineDownloadItem::finished` signal.

It is possible then to open the file in newly-created QWebEnginePage, set URL to a downloaded file and print this page. All of this can be done in background - without showing the page. Of course, some type of state machine is required to not print not loaded pages.